# Problem in performing quantile regression with quantreg

Tags: r, regression, survival, quantile-regression

I am performing a censored quantile regression on survival data to account for time differences in survival at certain percentiles in my cohort. I am using the [`quantreg`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/quantreg/quantreg.pdf) package from CRAN.

Here is a code that works as a reproducible example

```
id<-seq(1,2000, by=1)
set.seed(123)
months <- runif(2000, min=0, max=36) #Create a time variable
set.seed(123)
event <- sample(c(0,1), 2000, replace=TRUE, prob=c(0.9,0.2)) #Create a censor/event variable
set.seed(123)
sex <- sample(c(0,1), 2000, replace=TRUE, prob=c(0.55,0.45)) #Create a sex variable
df <- as.data.frame(cbind(id,months,event,sex))

#Generate some random NA to simulate real-world dataset
set.seed(123)
navector1 <- sample(seq(1,2000, by=1), 120, replace=FALSE) 
set.seed(123)
navector2 <- sample(seq(1,2000, by=1), 150, replace=FALSE)
set.seed(123)
navector3 <- sample(seq(1,2000, by=1), 200, replace=FALSE)
df$months <- replace(df$months, navector1, NA)
df$event <- replace(df$event, navector2, NA)
df$sex <- replace(df$sex, navector3, NA)

require(survival)
require(quantreg)
fit <- crq(Surv(months,event) ~ sex, method="Portnoy", data=df)
fit
summary(fit)
```

Note that in my `df` dataset you have a time variable (`months`), an event variable (`event`) and a grouping variable (`sex`). I have added some NA values at random to simulate observational, real-world data.

As you can see, `fit` store the result of the `crq` function. Here is the result:

```
Call:
crq(formula = Surv(months, event) ~ sex, data = df, method = "Portnoy")

Coefficients:
            tau= 0.2 tau= 0.4 tau= 0.6 tau= 0.8
(Intercept)       NA       NA       NA       NA
sex               NA       NA       NA       NA
```

These NA may be related to the fact that events are quite rare in my database, so that overall survival in both groups may be higher than 20% (i.e. 0.2 percentile).  However, I am interested in lower percentiles (which should report non-NA values). When I run the `summary(fit)` command, here is the result:

```
Error in B$A[1, , , drop = TRUE] : incorrect number of dimensions
```

And there is nothing that I tried that help my code works. Note that I tried to specify the `tau`, `taus` and `grid` attributes in the call of crq, but these seems not to affect the output (it keeps posting the "NA" table).

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Which package is `Surv()` from?

Comment: Sorry, it's from the 'survival' package - I've edited my code

Comment: Weird behavior indeed!

Comment: @yrx1702 yeah I know and cannot solve in any way - neither passing the tau argument to the call of crq, which seems the most suitable solution to me